# Get Distinct Rows By Two Columns With Ordering Desc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have ms sql table like following.

| ID | Num1 | Num2 | Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 | 4 | 3 |

I want to get distinct rows by num1 & num2 with highest range.
Query should return result like this.

| ID | Num1 | Num2 | Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 | 4 | 3 |

Num1 & Num2 values are grouped (please note that 2,1 and 1,2 are considered as same). If the ere are multiple 1,2 rows with the highest range is selected from that group.

So far I could return following but it contains Num1 & Num2 swapped rows (1,2 & 2,1...).

Query should return the column as in the 1st table and Num1&Num2 data cannot be swapped.

| ID | Num1 | Num2 | Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 | 4 | 3 |

Query I've tried

```
Select Max([ID]) As 'ID'
      ,Max([Num1]) As 'Num1'
      ,Max([Num2]) As 'Num2'
      ,Max([Range]) As 'Range'
    From [dbo].[Range]
    Group by Concat([Num1], [Num2])
    Order By Range desc
```

Comment: Why is an ID of 7 expected as the output from your query, given that 7 is neither the max ID value for the (1, 4) group, nor is 7 the ID for which the max range value occurs?

Comment: I've updated the quested. It should be ID with 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you're using SQLServer 2017+ you can use *string_agg* via an *apply* to create the condensed groupings required (this would easily support more than 2 columns if required) and a *row_number* solution for ordering by range:

```
with g as (
  select *, Row_Number() over(partition by grp order by range desc)rn
  from t
  cross apply (
    select String_Agg(n, '') within group(order by n) 
    from (values(num1), (num2))v(n) 
  )s(grp)
)
select Id, num1, num2, Range
from g
where rn = 1
order by id;
```

See [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aab01d50bf9a48f7834c5b0142a6005c)

Edit:

on SQL server 2014 you could substitute for the `for xml path` hack:

```
with g as (
  select *, Row_Number() over(partition by grp order by range desc)rn
  from t
  cross apply (
    select top(2) n
    from (values(num1), (num2))v(n) 
    order by n
    for xml path('')
  )s(grp)
)
select Id, num1, num2, Range
from g
where rn = 1
order by id;
```

Comment: I've checked the query and returned expected output. Unfortunately I'm using sql server 2014.

Comment: @AlexanderRaymak See edit above for SQLServer 2014 alternative

Answer (score 3):

We can use a least/greatest trick here along with aggregation.  Actually, we *can't* do that on SQL Server, which doesn't support these scalar functions, but we can still use `CASE` expressions:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MAX([Range]) OVER (PARTITION BY 
                  CASE WHEN Num1 < Num2 THEN Num1 ELSE Num2 END,
                  CASE WHEN Num1 < Num2 THEN Num2 ELSE Num1 END) AS MaxRange
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
                  CASE WHEN Num1 < Num2 THEN Num1 ELSE Num2 END,
                  CASE WHEN Num1 < Num2 THEN Num2 ELSE Num1 END
                  ORDER BY MaxRange DESC) rn
    FROM cte
)

SELECT ID, Num1, Num2, [Range]
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: @Gert I guess I was in a `GROUP BY` state of mind `:~)`

Comment: Num1 and Num2 should be returned as it is and cannot be swapped. I only need to take 1,2 or 2,1 with the highest range. But it should say which are the Num1 and Num2

Comment: @AlexanderRaymak Check the updated answer which does not alter the original order of the two values.